# Deploy Grails 4 app on JBoss 7 throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, grails, jboss, jboss7.x

**Steps to Reproduce**
Create default grails app:

1. grails create-app hello - grails 4.0.5 , openJDK 11 , gradle 6
2. Build deployable war using command - `grails war`
3. Try to deploy on JBossEAP 7.1 standalone

**Expected Behaviour**

Grails docs says:
Ideally you should be able to simply drop a WAR file created by Grails into any application server and it should work straight away.

**Actual Behaviour**

```
2021-01-15 06:47:28,216 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 203) Application run failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySourcePropertyResolver.processPropertySource(PropertySourcePropertyResolver.java:450)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.readPropertySources(DefaultEnvironment.java:459)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.start(DefaultEnvironment.java:311)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.start(DefaultEnvironment.java:63)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.startEnvironment(DefaultApplicationContext.java:228)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:186)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//grails.boot.GrailsApp.createApplicationContext(GrailsApp.groovy:155)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:97)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

2021-01-15 06:47:28,216 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 203) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."hello-0.1.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."hello-0.1.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:254)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySourcePropertyResolver.processPropertySource(PropertySourcePropertyResolver.java:450)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.readPropertySources(DefaultEnvironment.java:459)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.start(DefaultEnvironment.java:311)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.start(DefaultEnvironment.java:63)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.startEnvironment(DefaultApplicationContext.java:228)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:186)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//grails.boot.GrailsApp.createApplicationContext(GrailsApp.groovy:155)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:97)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at deployment.hello-0.1.war//org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.7.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
        ... 10 more

2021-01-15 06:47:28,220 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 3) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "hello-0.1.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"hello-0.1.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
2021-01-15 06:47:28,220 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 3) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "hello-0.1.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"hello-0.1.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
```

Comment: I am trying to make sense of the line numbers in your stack trace.  Is your project using version 1.3.7 of `micronaut-inject`?

Comment: `"gradle 6"` - By default Grails 4.0.5 apps are configured to build with Gradle 5.6.4.  Unclear if that will be relevant or not but that would be a good thing to rule out.

Comment: it is using micronaut-inject 1.1.4 , i havent mentioned any versions for micronaut-inject in build.gradle.